# Does $K[x]/(p(x))$ contain the splitting field of $p(x)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $K$ be a field. And $p(x)$ be an irreducible polynomial in $K[x]$. Then, does $K[x]/(p(x))$ contain the splitting field of $p(x)$ ?

If yes, can you give me the sketch of a proof ?

Comment: The splitting field is supposed to contain all the roots of the polynomial $p(x)$ whereas $K[x]/(p(x))$ will guarantee only one root of $p(x)$. It may contain all roots in cases when the extension $K[x]/(p(x))$ is normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not necessarily.  For a counterexample, take $K:=\mathbb{Q}$, $p(x):=x^3-2$.  Then $K[x]/(p(x))$ can be embedded in the reals as $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$, but this is not a splitting field as it does not
contain the complex roots of $p(x)$.

Comment: $x^3 - 2$, the eternal counterexample...